# How to achieve RAII with #pragma's?

Tags: c++, pragma, raii

Currently, I have the following piece of code:

```cpp
enum class Letters {
    A,
    B,
    C
};

#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wswitch"
        
Letters e(Letters::A);
switch(e){
    case Letters::A: break;
    case Letters::B: break;
}

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

I want to use something like this:

```cpp
class DiagnosticError {
public:
    constexpr DiagnosticError() {
        #pragma GCC diagnostic push
        #pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wswitch"
    }

    constexpr ~DiagnosticError() {
        #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
    }
};

enum class Letters {
    A,
    B,
    C
};

{
    constexpr DiagnosticError switchError;
        
    Letters e(Letters::A);
    switch(e){
        case Letters::A: break;
        case Letters::B: break;
    }
}
```

The code compiles fine under C++20, but without generating the error:

```
error: enumeration value 'C' not handled in switch [-Werror=switch]
   38 |         switch(e){
```

Why is that? Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: RAII is a runtime concept. You're trying to make C++ code run during compilation and that requires constexpr/consteval but will not work with #pragma. I kind of like your thinking though :) So in the #pragma case it is back to manually managing your pushes and pops

Comment: One way to achieve what you want is to make a code generator, and that generator would then emit the pragmas in the desired locations.

Comment: Also disabling warnings is something you should only do for code you have no control over (3rd party libraries). In all other cases just fix the warnings they exist for a reason. And missing a default/"C" case is definetly worthy of a warning ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pragmas are handled by too early a translation phase to apply something like a guard object to a block. The best you can do is write your macros to cut a bit on the boiler-plate

```
#define DIAG_ERR_PUSH(flags) _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push") DIAG_ERR_PUSH_(GCC diagnostic error flags)
#define DIAG_ERR_PUSH_(str) _Pragma(#str)

#define DIAG_POP() _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")

enum class Letters {
    A,
    B,
    C
};

DIAG_ERR_PUSH("-Wswitch")
    
Letters e(Letters::A);
switch(e){
    case Letters::A: break;
    case Letters::B: break;
}

DIAG_POP()
```

Since C++11 we have the `_Pragma` form of the directive, to embed pragmas into other expansions. `DIAG_ERR_PUSH(...)` takes the place of your guard object, and `DIAG_POP()` delimits the region (instead of curly braces).

Not quite RAII, but sure better than having to type *all* the minutia for the pragma. [Here's a live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/adEoIegXU5ZU1IuZ).

Answer (score 1):

No, all preprocessor directives get read and interpreted in place before any compilation takes place (it's actually a separate step on some compilers). In other words, your `#pragma` was already applied to exactly the lines you see in code between the start and end parts.

It seems what you're after is source code generation, which would require an additional tool to pre-process your file and insert those statements where you want them (or use a compiler that allows you to inject hooks to generate them at build time, like clang).